# Sudoku solver, not backtracking solver

Tags: java, sudoku

The past few weeks I've been working on a sudoku game.
The game as a lot of features such as: play game, print sudoku, solve sudoku.

The solve function uses conventional backtracking but thats not the issue, the issue is that I need the game to be able to produce a humanely solvable sudoku, for that I need a method that will be able to solve a sudoku as a human would do it.

If anyone could help me work out the mechanics of how this could be done I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It would be useful if we knew what your code was. Do you use pure backtracking (known commonly as brute force) or do you have a logical solving algorithm that uses backtracking only as a last resort?

Comment: If a sudoku (as all should) has a unique solution, the solution can be solved by pure logic and can be solved by a human.  So what are you really looking for?

Comment: Can't you just create a random matrix which obeys Sudoku's rules, and then remove radomnly one number, solve it using the backtracker to make sure there exist a solution and it is unique, if it is solvable then you remove another one and repit, till there is no solution or solution it is not unique, then you just keep the previous sudoku. I think this would be O(n^3)?

Comment: @k_g I have a solve method that uses standard backtracking(brute force) but what i need is a method with logical solving algorithm as you mentioned.

Comment: @DonRoby Don Roby, yes a normal sudoku is solvable, but not if you randomly removed the wrong numbers, making it unsolvable using common logic.

Comment: @mancuernita I did make random matrix obaying sudoku rules, with that I take a 50%, 55% and 65% chance of removing a number (depending on deficulty), running through all numbers. Wouldn't the backtrack you spoke of always return a solve tho?

Answer (score 4):

An overwhelming collection of *Sudoku* solving strategies for human players is nicely presented and explained on [Andrew Stuart's Sudoku page](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm):

> ```
> **Show Possibles**         
> 1: Hidden Singles      
> 2: Naked Pairs/Triples     
> 3: Hidden Pairs/Triples    
> 4: Naked Quads     
> 5: Pointing Pairs      
> 6: Box/Line Reduction      
> **Tough Strategies**  
> 7: X-Wing      
> 8: Simple Colouring        
> 9: Y-Wing      
> 10: Sword-Fish         
> 11: XYZ Wing       
> **Diabolical Strategies** 
> 12: X-Cycles       
> 13: XY-Chain       
> 14: 3D Medusa      
> 15: Jelly-Fish         
> 16: Unique Rectangles      
> 17: Extended Unique Rect.      
> 18: Hidden Unique Rect's       
> 19: WXYZ Wing      
> 20: Aligned Pair Exclusion         
> **Extreme Strategies**    
> 21: Grouped X-Cycles       
> 22: Empty Rectangles       
> 23: Finned X-Wing      
> 24: Finned Sword-Fish      
> 25: Altern. Inference Chains   
> 26: Sue-de-Coq         
> 27: Digit Forcing Chains       
> 28: Nishio Forcing Chains  
> 29: Cell Forcing Chains        
> 30: Unit Forcing Chains        
> 31: Almost Locked Sets         
> 32: Death Blossom      
> 33: Pattern Overlay Method         
> 34: Quad Forcing Chains        
> **"Trial and Error"** 
> 35: Bowman's Bingo
> ```

As a fairly frequent player, I would judge everything beyond strategy 11 as "no fun anymore". But that is probably a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a quick random sudoku, you can use a particular way of creating a valid sudoku pattern with the following algorithm I figured out a while ago:

```
You initialize an array with a randomized set of the numbers 1 to 9, 
technically it's easier if you initialize 3 arrays each with 3 length.
You can have these numbers be randomized, thus create a different sudoku.

[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]
Then you shift these:
[7 8 9] [1 2 3] [4 5 6]
[4 5 6] [7 8 9] [1 2 3]

Then you shift the numbers inside the arrays:

[3 1 2] [6 4 5] [9 7 8]
Then you shift the arrays themselves again:
[9 7 8] [3 1 2] [6 4 5]
[6 4 5] [9 7 8] [3 1 2]

Then you shift the numbers inside the arrays:

[2 3 1] [5 6 4] [8 9 7]
Then you shift the arrays again:
[8 9 7] [2 3 1] [5 6 4]
[5 6 4] [8 9 7] [2 3 1]
```

And you'll have the final set of sudoku table:

```
[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]
[7 8 9] [1 2 3] [4 5 6]
[4 5 6] [7 8 9] [1 2 3]
[3 1 2] [6 4 5] [9 7 8]
[9 7 8] [3 1 2] [6 4 5]
[6 4 5] [9 7 8] [3 1 2]
[2 3 1] [5 6 4] [8 9 7]
[8 9 7] [2 3 1] [5 6 4]
[5 6 4] [8 9 7] [2 3 1]
```

Which is valid. Afterwards, you can take out some numbers, and you can check with the algorithm you already have whether it has a single solution, or multiple. If removing a certain number produces multiple, then either undo it and end the removal, or try removing another.

Comment: I already have an algorithm which can produce any random sudoku board i ask it for, all being valid sudoku boards.

Comment: Oh, okay, I thought this was what you were looking for. So you already had the valid board, but you needed a way to remove numbers and keep it solvable. Apart from picking out numbers at random and checking how many solutions there are, and if there is only one solution then keep the removal, if not then undo the removal and try another is the only way I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Also I have a method to run through the board removing random numbers at a specified percentage(fx 50% chance of removing a number). What I need is an example or an explanation of how to verify if the puzzly generated is humanly solvable, meaning brute force(backtracking) is not useful here.

Comment: Apart from some form of clever iterative bruteforcing, I'm not sure what you can do.

Comment: Technically if you maintain the list of what are usable numbers at given cells in a given state and iterate those lists to bruteforce, it significantly reduces the number of tries you need to check (from 9^n).